# Redirect on spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, web

I wrote login system on spring-boot but there is a problem when I want to login, spring take login and password from form but cannot redirect to the account page.

[Controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TFdbR.png)

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rXnxs.png)

```
 @PostMapping(value = "user/login")
public String login(Model model, HttpSession session, @RequestParam("login") String login, @RequestParam("password") String password) {
    try {
        User user = userService.checkLogin(login, password);
        if (user == null) {
            model.addAttribute("err", "Login Valid login and password");
            return "/login";
        } else {
            if (user.getRole().equals(userService.Role_Admin)) {
                userService.addUserInSession(user, session);

                return "/admin/account";
            } else if (user.getRole().equals(userService.Role_Student)) {
                userService.addUserInSession(user, session);
                return "/student/account";
            } else {
                model.addAttribute("err", "Invalid User Role");
                return "/login";
            }
        } } catch (UserException ex) {
        model.addAttribute("err", ex.getMessage());
        return "/login";
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

First you should use `redirect` prefix :

```
//...
return "redirect:/admin/account";
// ...
return "redirect:/student/account";
```

More info here : https://www.baeldung.com/spring-redirect-and-forward

Second thing -from your screenshots- I saw that your controller is configured to handle `POST` requests, but you sent a `GET` request from the browser : *localhost:8080/user/login?login=isi&password=test*

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to replace `@PostMapping` with `@RequestMapping` so as to allow both `POST` and `GET` requests. Your login request is a `POST` request while the redirect is a `GET` request.
Secondly, redirects in spring boot are prefixed with `redirect:/`. Therefore your redirect code should look like:

```
return "redirect:/admin/account"
```

Answer (score 0):

I already corrected but there is a problem it redirect to admin page but cannot show the content of the corresponding page